# What is rxjs equivalent to Array.some()?

Tags: rxjs

If you want to iterate over an array to see if some elements pass a condition, you do something like this:

```
let result = [1, 34, 65, 3, 7].some(entry => entry > 10)
// result => true
```

What is the rxjs equivalent for doing this?
I imagine its something like this (which isn't totally correct):

```
// functions return Observable<number>
from([fn1, fn2, fn2]).pipe(
  map(fn => fn()),
  takeUntil(data > 100)
).subscribe(data => console.log(`result:${data}`)
```

(The returned value from fn is always asynchronous)

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent would be the opposite of [`every`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/every):

```
from([1, 34, 65, 3, 7]).pipe(
  every((item) => item < 10),
  map((isEvery) => !isEvery)
).subscribe((e) => console.log(e)) //true
```

I don't think there is a native `some`, but you can always just create it yourself by using those two pipes.

Comment: This one has a difference though - `Array.some` will stop iterating the array as soon as it finds an element matching the predicate. Negating `every` on the other hand will always need to go through the whole list of elements.

Comment: @olivarra1 yep, that is indeed a difference. Your answer is a nice solution if that is an issue!

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of `Array.some`, i.e. to check whether if there's at least an element that passes a condition, I think it would be a combination of `find`

```
const some = (predicate) => source$ =>
  source$.pipe(
    find(predicate),
    mapTo(true),
    defaultIfEmpty(false)
  );
```

This way, as soon as there's an element satisfying the predicate, you'll receive a true (and the observable would complete, as there won't be more values coming). And if none of them match, then you'll receive a false as soon as the source completes.

The upside of using this instead of negating `every` is that you can get the `true` as soon as it matches the predicate, instead of having to wait for the whole observable to complete.

Extra: note that `find` is an existing operator, but it's just sugar for `filter(predicate)` + `take(1)`

Edit: Oh! I didn't see that you don't have an Observable of numbers, but observable of functions that return observables of numbers.

In that case, you need to flatten it - And using the `some` operator described above:

```
from([fn1,fn2,fn2]).pipe( // where functions return Observable<number>
  mergeMap(fn => fn()),
  some(data => data > 100)
).subscribe(data => console.log(`result:${data}`)
```

Or if you don't want to declare your `some` operator, just use the internal bits directly:

```
from([fn1,fn2,fn2]).pipe( // where functions return Observable<number>
  mergeMap(fn => fn()),
  find(data => data > 100),
  mapTo(true),
  defaultIfEmpty(false)
).subscribe(data => console.log(`result:${data}`)
```

Note that you have 2 possible operators for flattening the observables: `concatMap` will subscribe to each observable one-by-one, waiting for the previous one to complete before subscribing to the next one (preserving the order of resolved values), while `mergeMap` will subscribe to all the observables as they keep coming (but then if a later observable is faster than a previous one, the values emitted won't be in the same order).

Comment: If you want to create `some` as a pipeable operator and have typescript follow the typing, I *think* the function signature would look like: `function some<T>(fn: (v: T) => boolean ): OperatorFunction<T, boolean>`

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to iterate over an array to see if all elements pass a condition, you do something like this: let result = [1,34,65,3,7].some(entry=>entry>10) // returns true;

Wrong. you need to use `every` to check whether all elements pass a condition or not
some is used if  any element sequence satisfies a condition

It is going to be same for RX.js as well.

```
from([1, 34, 65, 3, 7]).pipe(
  every((item) => item < 10),
  .... //rest of the operations
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to `some` operator in RxJs, at least afaik. At the same time it is possible to implement something equivalent, like this

```
const fn1 = () => of(100).pipe(delay(100))
const fn2 = () => of(200).pipe(delay(200))
const fn3 = () => of(300).pipe(delay(300))

from([fn1,fn2,fn3]).pipe( // where functions return Observable<number>
        concatMap(fn=>fn()),
        filter(d => d > 100),
        toArray()
    ).subscribe({
      next: data => console.log(`Are there elements grearer than 100?`, data.length > 0)
    })
```

Similar result could be obtained using the `reduce` RxJs operator.

You have to notice that this implementation requires to scan the entire array of functions before reaching to a conclusive result.

If the array is long, then you may want to exit as soon as you find an element emitted that satisfies the rule. In this case. you can consider to use `first` operator, but you have to manage some more complexity: the result has to be dealt by 2 methods of the subscriber, `complete` for a success and `error` for not success (with some additional logic to understand the nature of the error), and you need also to accept the idea of a statefull implementation, i.e. the use of a variable to hold the value filtered

```
const fn1 = () => of(100).pipe(delay(100))
const fn2 = () => of(200).pipe(delay(200))
const fn3 = () => of(300).pipe(delay(300))

let found = false;

from([fn1,fn2,fn3]).pipe( // where functions return Observable<number>
        concatMap(fn=>fn()),
        first(d => d > 100),
        tap(() => found = true)
    ).subscribe({
      error: (e) => {
        if (e.name === "EmptyError") {
          console.log(`Are there elements grearer than 100?`, found)
        }
        else {
          console.error(e)
        }
        },
      complete: () => console.log(`Are there elements grearer than 100?`, found),
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The 100% rxjs operator equivalent to [array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

const some = cb => source => source.pipe(
  map(src => src.some(cb))
)

const even = element => element % 2 === 0;

of([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(
  some(even)
).subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

- The above code only works for arrays emitted as source
- I expect this to work for you, because of the fact, that your fn's return values synchronous and you could use [of](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of)
- If you only want to emit this pipe once I recommend using the [take](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take) operator.

The rxjs operator equivalent to [array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) implemented with single emits:

```js
const { from } = rxjs;
const { map, scan, filter } = rxjs.operators;

const some = cb => source => source.pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => ([...acc, curr]), []),
  map(src => src.some(cb)),
  filter(Boolean)
)

const even = element => element % 2 === 0;

from([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(
  some(even)
).subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

- The above code works for single values emitted as source
- If you only want to emit this pipe once I recommend using the [take](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take) operator